# Apache - Rewriting trailing extension with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

To remove trailing extension (a `.php` in this case), I have tried the following two set of rules

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (\S*?)/(.*?)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule !\.php$ %1.php [NC,L]
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)\.php$ $1 [NC,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule !\.php$ %1.php [NC,L]
```

To convert a url like `test.com/test.php` to `test.com/test`, the first one works while the second one ends up looping infinitely. The `rewrite_log` is just confusing, so can anyone tell what is the problem with the second set?

> PS: The rules might be inefficient or even not sufficient for a case like `test.com` but that's not the issue. I just want to understand how the rewrite is working BTS.

Comment: Your first rule works because you are using `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable.Your second rule `RewriteRule ^(.*?)\.php$ $1 [NC,L,R= 301]`

is unconditionally redirecting `file.php` to `/file` so this loops.

Comment: You could use `END` flag in your second rule to avoid the looping error `RewriteRule !\.php$ % 1.php [END]` .

Comment: @starkeen ... if this is in an `.htaccess` file (as implied by the tags) then aren't `[END]` and `[L]` basically synonymous?

Comment: @starkeen Once `file.php` becomes file, shouldn't the rewriterule not satisfy the condition and thus skip the it?

Comment: @AnuragDaolagajao: `mod_rewrite` rules are run in a loop until one or more rules match  a condition or pattern. `L` flag merely works as `continue` in a loop but `END` (available with Apache 2.4+) works as `break` and stops looping. Using `%{THE_REQUEST}` doesn't cause looping since `%{THE_REQUEST}` doesn't change with application of other rules whereas `REQUEST_URI` gets updated after every rule execution.

Comment: @anubhava Oh so `THE_REQUEST` stays the same even after all the redirects whereas the `REQUEST_URI` changes due to the rewrites?

Comment: Yes that's correct `THE_REQUEST` represents original request received by Apache from browser and that value doesn't change after execution of 1 or more internal rewrite rules.

Comment: @CD001 `END` and `L` are two different flags. `END` terminates the the internal Rule's processing when a RewriteRule is applied .  But with `L` server reads the `.htaccess` file multiple time to serve the internal  request.

Comment: @starkeen - yeah, but I thought the distinction didn't really have much effect if used in an `.htaccess` file (unlike say `httpd-vhosts.conf`) is all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, in the first case, there is no looping using `%{THE_REQUEST}` as the value is static and doesn't change once it is received by the server even after redirecting / "looping". So the rule will remove trailing `.php` and redirect. As the rewrite rule is substituting values from `%{THE_REQUEST}` in the `rewritecond`, after redirection, the value will not contain the trailing `.php` and thus proceed on to the second `rewritecond` and then finally redirect internally. After a second redirect, both the conditions will fail to match thus stopping the process

Whereas in the second case, the rewrite rule checks values from the `uri` which will remove `.php` and redirect. After redirection, the second rule will internally redirect back to the uri with php extension. Then finally in the supposed third final check which is supposed to not match both the rules, the first rule will again be matching thus infinitely looping the entire process.